# Combining a static char* and a constant string

Tags: string, static, append, fstream

I want to be able to append a constant string to the end of another string in the form of a char*, and then use the resulting string as an argument for open(). Here's what it looks like:

file1.cpp

```
#include "string.h"

file2 foo;

char* word = "some";
foo.firstWord = word; //I want the file2 class to be able to see "some"
```

file2.h

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#define SECONDWORD "file.txt"

class file2{
public:
    file2();
    static char* firstWord;
    static char* fullWord;

private:
    ofstream stream;

}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "file2.h"

char* file2::firstWord;
char* file2::fullWord;

fullWord = firstWord + SECONDWORD; //so fullWord is now "somefile.txt" ,I know this doesn't work, but basically I am trying to figure out this part

file2::file2(){
    stream.open(fullWord);
}
```

So I am not very well versed in C++, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++-style solution might be the following.

```
#include <string>

char* a = "file";
char* b = ".txt";

...

stream.open((std::string(a) + b).c_str());
```

What happens here? First, `std::string(a)` creates a temporary `std::string` object. Than `b` value is added to it. At last, `c_str()` method returns a c-style string which contains `a + b`.